# Fluter/Dart code loading over network

Tags: flutter

Recently, I watched the first introduction of Flutter originally named Sky on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=10&v=PnIWl33YMwA . 
At 1:54 Eric Seidel says something like this - **This all is loaded over the network. Dart code of the network.** What happenend to it in Flutter?
Is it possible to load Dart code like new versions directly over the network without using the AppStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure Eric was talking about the data or the actual code. It does sound like he meant both.

It may have been possible to load code over the network because on these early days they shipped the dart VM on releases and code was JIT compiled. Since late 2015 Flutter moved to Dart's AOT compilation (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqE4u8s8Iik)).

So no, it's not possible to update your flutter apps through the network.

Answer (score 1):

**This all is loaded over the network. Dart code of the network**

After watching the video, I got the context of the line. It means the data getting fetched from the network and the code written is in the Dart rather than Java.